# Can't log into Amazon EC2 Instance with key pair

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, pki

I can connect to my **Amazon EC2** instance via the `pem` file that I've been given.

I do something like this

```
ssh -i <mykeyname>.pem ubuntu@<myexternalip>
```

and it works ok.

But now I need a passwordless login to my instance, so I create a key pair as shown [here](http://queirozf.com/reminders/creating-a-private-public-key-pair-on-ubuntu)
and send my `.pub` file to my remote instance and put it under the `.ssh` directory with the name `authorized_keys` but I still can't connect!

I keep getting an error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Are all other forms of logging in (apart from .pem files) disallowed by default on **EC2 Instances**?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Which SSH client are you using ?

Comment: ermm I'm just using ssh from my local ubuntu command line...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If the original key pair was working, why do you want to create another one ? Is it because the original key pair has a passphrase and you don't want one ?

Comment: No, it's because i want to create a git server on my remote server, and i can only do it using an unpassworded ssh login...I know it's possible because i've done it on another server (also amazon) but I can't seem to reproduce it on this server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it wasn't an **SSH** problem at all. The problem was that, when I call `sudo`, i forgot that the user changes to **root**... and obviously I hadn't set up keys for the **root** user so it kept failing on me...

I solved it by using `sudo -u actual_user` instead.

Thanks to **cmn** on git@freenode for helping me see this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you check the ssh output (ssh -v), if you haven't already. Sometimes the debug messages can help pinpoint the problem. That said, this feels like a file permission issue. Make sure the .pub file can be read by non-root users.